# 'Invalid format specifier' error when using pandas describe() or head() in google colab

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

When I use pandas describe() or head() method on a dataframe on Google colab,
I get 'Invalid format specifier' error.
However,when I run the same code on Jupiter notebook, it works fine.
What could be the problem?
All the other methods (such as info() ) work fine on **both** jupiter notebook and colab:

```
train = pd.read_csv('./input/train_V2.csv')
train.describe()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    697                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    698                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 699             printer.pretty(obj)
    700             printer.flush()
    701             return stream.getvalue()

17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1427                 [
   1428                     formatter(val) if not m else na_rep
-> 1429                     for val, m in zip(values.ravel(), mask.ravel())
   1430                 ]
   1431             ).reshape(values.shape)

ValueError: Invalid format specifier
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    332                 pass
    333             else:
--> 334                 return printer(obj)
    335             # Finally look for special method names
    336             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

17 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1427                 [
   1428                     formatter(val) if not m else na_rep
-> 1429                     for val, m in zip(values.ravel(), mask.ravel())
   1430                 ]
   1431             ).reshape(values.shape)

ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

All the other methods works fine on **both** jupiter notebook and colab:

```
train.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4446966 entries, 0 to 4446965
Data columns (total 29 columns):
 #   Column           Dtype  
---  ------           -----  
 0   Id               object 
 1   groupId          object 
 2   matchId          object 
 3   assists          int8   
 4   boosts           int8   
 5   damageDealt      float32
 6   DBNOs            int8   
 7   headshotKills    int8   
 8   heals            int8   
 9   killPlace        int8   
 10  killPoints       int16  
 11  kills            int8   
 12  killStreaks      int8   
 13  longestKill      float32
 14  matchDuration    int16  
 15  matchType        object 
 16  maxPlace         int8   
 17  numGroups        int8   
 18  rankPoints       int16  
 19  revives          int8   
 20  rideDistance     float32
 21  roadKills        int8   
 22  swimDistance     float32
 23  teamKills        int8   
 24  vehicleDestroys  int8   
 25  walkDistance     float32
 26  weaponsAcquired  int16  
 27  winPoints        int16  
 28  winPlacePerc     float32
dtypes: float32(6), int16(5), int8(14), object(4)
memory usage: 339.3+ MB
```

Comment: What pandas versions are you running?  Run `pd.__version__` in both places.

Comment: Did you change this anywhere in your notebook? pd.options.display.float_format